# Create a site script using Get-SPOSiteScriptFromWeb cmdlet error

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-discussion-board

I am trying to create a site script from an existing team site but when I run the script that I followed from this [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/get-spositescriptfromweb?view=sharepoint-ps) it asks me for the WebURL [WebURL Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dAPT.png), even though it is in the script, then when I provide it at the prompt it gives me the error [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mn6oD.png).

I am not new to site scripts but have not used them much.  I would like to create one from an existing site that I have created for the PM team.  Please advise. I am using the latest SharePoint Online Management Shell and I am logged in.  I am also a Global Admin.

Any assistance would be helpful as I have done everything I can think of to do and Googled my heart out but cannot figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot you posted, it looks like you did not include ` (back tick) at the end of each row in your command. Those are necessary in order for PowerShell to understand entirety of your command which spans across multiple rows, like in the following example:

```
Get-SPOSiteScriptFromWeb `
    -WebUrl https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/template `
    -IncludeBranding `
    -IncludeTheme `
    -IncludeRegionalSettings `
    -IncludeSiteExternalSharingCapability `
    -IncludeLinksToExportedItems `
    -IncludedLists ("Shared Documents", "Lists/Project Activities")
```

Alternative would be to enter entire command and all parameters in single row, like this:

```
Get-SPOSiteScriptFromWeb -WebUrl https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/template -IncludeBranding -IncludeTheme -IncludeRegionalSettings -IncludeSiteExternalSharingCapability -IncludeLinksToExportedItems -IncludedLists ("Shared Documents", "Lists/Project Activities")
```